# How do I use all-argument constructor for JPA Entity with JoinColumn?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a Spring Boot application (REST repositories, JPA, PostgreSQL) to host REST APIs for a project. Users are able to select a species of plant to grow. Here is a part of the code of the entity that stores data about the plants associated to the User.

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "plant")
public class Plant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "plant_id")
    private UUID plantID;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "species_id")
    private PlantSpecies species;

    @Column(name = "date_of_planting")
    private Date dateOfPlanting;
}
```

I'm trying to create an API that creates a new instance of `Plant` and saves it to my database. Ideally, the request should give me a `userID` and a `speciesID`, and I should me able to construct a new `Plant` with something like this:

```java
    // PROBLEM HERE
    public Plant(String userID, String speciesID) {
        this.user = userID;
        this.species = speciesID;
        this.dateOfPlanting = new Date();
    }
```

The table in my database stores only the respective foreign keys (strings), so if I need to insert a new record, I should be able to simply store strings, right? But in the Entity, the data isn't stored as strings, they're objects of those classes. The constructor code is obviously wrong, in that case. I understand that my logic is flawed, but I'm unable to pinpoint where and how to fix it.

I have the option of querying the User and PlantSpecies tables to get the record, and passing that into this constructor, which will solve my error, but I feel like that's wrong. I shouldn't have to fetch an entire record to store the ID that I already have with me. I'd appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have to use JPA as you are using, you have to first fetch the user from database and then set this user object in your constructor of `Plant` Entity. This is how JPA works if you have to relate one entity object to another entity object. If you doesn't want to fetch user first and relate that user object to the `Plant` object then you have to remove the relationship `@ManyToOne` annotation and just store it as normal data column of either String type or Integer type whatever suits in your scenario.
One thing to take care is that the specified user id does exist in you database.

Comment: @Naqi I was hoping I didn't have to go either route :/ I guess I'll use the first option you mentioned for now. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer, please accept this as an answer to your question. It may help someone else also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use JPA as you are using, you have to first fetch the user from database and then set this user object in your constructor of `Plant` Entity. This is how JPA works if you have to relate one entity object to another entity object. If you doesn't want to fetch user first and relate that user object to the Plant object then you have to remove the relationship `@ManyToOne` annotation and just store it as normal data column of either String type or Integer type whatever suits in your scenario. One thing to take care is that the specified user id does exist in you database before assigning this id to the plant object